# Partial Differenial Equation

Tags: calculus

I have to solve this problem:
Assume that the function $y(x,t)$ satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial t^2}=4
\end{equation}
with $y(x,0)=\sin x$ and $\partial y / \partial t (x,0)=0$. Using $u=x+t$ and $v=x-t$, find $y(x,t)$.

I found the relation between ${y}_{uv}$ and ${y}_{vu}$ by applying Chain Rule.
So I got following result.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial u \partial v}+\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial v \partial u} = 2
\end{equation}
I need the guideline to start the solution.

Comment: Assume that the second partials of $y$ are continuous in your domain, hence $y_{uv} = y_{vu}$ which implies $$y_{uv} = 1$$ Now just integrate. You should get $$y(u,v) = uv + g(v) + h(u)$$ for arbitrary functions $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Just so you can check, I get that the final solution is $$y(x, t) = \frac{\sin(x+t) + \sin(x-t)}{2} - 2t^{2}$$